# Unable to convert date to particular format in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, nsdateformatter

I am getting some date string from server, like "2021-06-25"

If it is today date or yesterday date, I have to show like **Today** or **Yesterday**.
Else I have to show **25 June 2021**
For Today and Yesterday date its working fine.

But, If its other day, it is showing **25 Jun 2021**

How to show **21 June 2021**

```
static func getDay(_ nowDay: String) -> String {
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let journalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: nowDay)
        
        if let convertedDate = journalDate {
            let relativeDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            relativeDateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
            relativeDateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            relativeDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
            relativeDateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
            let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
            inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return relativeDateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate)
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should always set the locale before setting the date style or format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the full name of the month, use `.long` rather than `.medium` as the date style:

```
relativeDateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
```

Also note that you can use a `ISO8601DateFormatter` to parse `nowDay`, since it is in ISO-8601 format:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
let journalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: nowDay)
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you